# calling the __str__ method to produce output?

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a program whose instructions specify "The **str** method must not contain any print statements and must return a string". So I've defined the function (within a the Employee class) as follows:

```
def __str__(self):
        return "\nThe employee's name is " + self.__employeeName + \
            "\nTotal regular hours worked: " + str(format(self.__regHours)) + \
            "\nTotal overtime hours worked: " + str(format(self.__otHours)) + \
            "\nTotal hours worked: " + str(format(self.__regHours + self.__otHours)) + \
            "\nEmployee's pay rate: $" + str(format(self.__hourlyPayRate, ".2f")) + \
            "\nMonthly regular pay: $" + str(format(self.getMonthlyRegPay(), ".2f")) + \
            "\nMonthly overtime pay: $" + str(format(self.getMonthlyOtPay(), ".2f")) + \
            "\nMonthly gross pay: $" + str(format(self.getGrossPay(), ".2f")) + \
            "\nMonthly taxes: $" + str(format(self.getTaxes(), ".2f")) + \
            "\nMonthly net pay: $" + str(format(self.getNetPay() - self.getTaxes(), ".2f"))
```

And I've created this instance of the Employee class in a separate file:

```
employee = EmployeeClass_New.Employee()

        employee.setEmployeeName()
        employee.setHourlyPayRate()
        employee.setHoursWorked()

        employeeName = employee.getEmployeeName()
        hourlyPayRate = employee.getHourlyPayRate()
        regHours = employee.getRegHours()
        otHours = employee.getOtHours()

        regPay = employee.getMonthlyRegPay()
        otPay = employee.getMonthlyOtPay()
        grossPay = employee.getGrossPay()
        taxes = employee.getTaxes()
        netPay = employee.getNetPay()

        **print(f"{str(employee)}")**

        repeat = input("Type 'yes' to input another employee or 'no' to quit: ")
```

My question pertains to the bolded part as I can only get this to output by printing it. I tried calling it like this:

```
employee.__str__()
```

but that didn't do anything...my question is, am I violating my professors instructions but doing this? Is there a way to call **str** that makes it produce output? All the articles I read look to print this method but I want to be very sure since my professor will give me a 0 for this assignment if I violate this rule.

Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this language but if I had to guess, `__str__` is called automatically when you convert the object to a string. You still have to *do* something with that string, such as `print` it out.

Comment: The language is Python! okay, so there's no way that calling __str__ would output (print) to the console just by calling it? You'd definitely need to use a print statement?

Comment: I think the "The str method must not contain any print statements and must return a string" means that within the `def __str__(self)` you must not use any print statements, There is no other way to show output...

Answer (score 1):

> The ***str*** method must not ...

The limitation is that the method *itself* must not contain `print` statements. You have met that requirement, returning a string for some *other* piece of code to use as it sees fit.

Unless you using the REPL where non-`None` expressions are printed auto-magically, you'll *definitely* have to `print` the string *outside* of the method in order to see that it works. That is no way violates the requirements given, since it's not *in* the method.